# Kohana 3.3 Routing Issue

Tags: .htaccess, routes, kohana

This route I am using works perfectly on local MAMP server, but not Dreamhost or HostPapa. I figured it was just a case sensitivity issue, but from what I can tell everything looks fine.

**Error Message**

```
Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL panel/asset/warranty/edit was not found on this server.
```

**Route:**

```
Route::set('panel/asset', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))',
    array(
        'directory' => 'panel/asset',
        'controller' => 'warranty',
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'action' => 'edit',
    ));
```

**Controller:** Controller/Panel/Asset/Warranty.php

```
class Controller_Panel_Asset_Warranty extends Controller_Site_AdminTemplate
```

**.htaccess**

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

SetEnv KOHANA_ENV DEVELOPMENT

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Required for dreamhost
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|user_guide|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule .* index.php?$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Am I missing something obvious? Routing always gives me such grief... /annoyed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a parameter to be a hard-coded string, do not put it in the regex array. Only use the regex array when you actually use some regex feature in the values.

This would be better. You could use the regex array to make sure id are digits, which is a valid reason to use it.

```
Route::set('panel/asset', 'panel/asset(/warranty(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'panel/asset',
        'controller' => 'warranty',
        'action' => 'edit',
    ));
```

This won't help you with the problem at hand though, if the URI haden't matched a route the exception read `Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]:Unable to find a route to match the URI: panel/asset/warranty/edit.`

The exception is telling you Kohana is looking for a route to match the URI `panel/asset/warranty/edit` I assume that is what you want. So the problem would be somewhere in your application, not the .htaccess file.

There are only two methods which have the following block of code in it.

```
throw HTTP_Exception::factory(404,
    'The requested URL :uri was not found on this server.',
    array(':uri' => $this->request->uri())
)->request($this->request);
```

Those methods are [Request_Client_Internal::execute_request()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Request_Client_Internal#execute_request) and [Controller::execute()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Controller#execute).

Have you placed some kind of debug statement in `Controller/Panel/Asset/Warranty.php` to see if it is found and executed? Because while reproducing I somehow the file was executed but class_exists('Controller_Panel_Asset_Warranty', FALSE) returned FALSE. When I copied the class name from your question and replaced the one I typed myself with it it suddenly worked. If I undid the paste it stopped working again. I checked letter for letter and my editor showed me the exact same thing before and after.

I hope this helps you narrow it down.

Comment: Yeah I've done all sorts of debugs inside the Warranty file with no luck.

If I echo out the $prefix inside the execute_request(). It's showing me "Controller_Panel_asset_". Some how that "asset" is being lowercase." I'm still looking into this as I write this.

Comment: I just tossed in a small hack into execute_request(). Checking for "/" in $directory. If so, explode, uppercase each in the array and put it all back together.